# Issue with export-excel Powershell

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell, windows-services, export-to-excel

I've created a Powershell script to fetch data from an Azure database.
Until January, I used ADAL authentication (login and password) and the Send-SQLDataToExcel command. Now I have to change it and use Token. I am getting data from an Azure database via PowerShell. i use this code:

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$connection.AccessToken = $access_token
$connection.Open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection)
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$dataadapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
$dataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=7200
\[void\]$dataadapter.fill($dataset)
$dataset.Tables | Export-Excel $fullpath
$connection.Close()
```

The amount of data is large, around 33,000 records and over 200 columns per file. I'm looking for an idea how I can write data faster, because at the moment, writing to a file is over 1 hour per company. I can't use export-csv.

I tried using invoke-sqlcmd but the write time is the same as above idea.
Is it possible to add token to connectionString in Send-SQLDataToExcel ?
For now I use 5.1 PS version

I tried using invoke-sqlcmd but the write time is the same as above idea.
Is it possible to add token to connectionString in Send-SQLDataToExcel ?

Comment: invoke-sqlcm is designed to archive database very quickly and is the fastest method for connecting to the database.  If you are getting slow response it must be for other reasons.  You database may be fragmented, you may have a poor connection, you may be going through a virus checker (or firewall), you database may be on a filesystem that is running slow.  My first question are you on same machine as the database?  What type of disk is the database located?  Is the Database Attached to a Server (or just using mdf file).  What is you connection string?

Comment: _"I can't use export-csv"_ Why not?

Comment: Is the PowerShell script executing on the SQL Server itself, or is the SQL Server located remotely? Is the Excel file being written to a local disk, or is it being written over a Network Share or to some kind of blob storage? This sounds like it could be a network/connectivity issue, either transferring data from the SQL Server to the PowerShell host, or transferring data from the PowerShell host to wherever the Excel file is stored. The MS-TDS protocol, being very chatty and originally designed for LAN connections, performs badly when it encounters the latencies of open internet connections.

Comment: @jdweng response is very fast, because when i tried get data from azure database and after 2 min I seen result in my console. A lot of time takes save to excel around 55 min+. I am not on same machine s the database. I run script on one of VMs in my company. Database is on server out of my domain. I not able to respons on your 2nd and 3 question but i can give you my connection string: connectionString = "Server=tcp:$sqlServerUrl,1433;Initial Catalog=$database;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;"

Comment: @Theo I can't use csv, because It's part of bigger process and Business require excel. Today i will try convert CSv to excel

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Server SQL is located remotely.  Data are written to a local disk.

Comment: As already mentioned the MS-TDS protocol is horrible when met by the latencies of the open internet. I would suggest executing the PowerShell script in the Azure environment as close to the SQL Server(s) as possible, exporting its results to Azure blob storage. Downloading the exported results from Azure blob storage would be much, much faster.

Comment: Looks like issue is save to excel.  Slow time could either be driver or Disk you are writing to.  check disk to make sure it is not full or fragmented.  Writing to CSV is a good suggestion. I suspect drive may have issue with the number of columns.